# Meaning of this python modulo operator exercise?

Tags: python

I just got started with Python PCEP course material on netacad.com.

I've come across the following exercises:

```
   2 % -4 = -2
   2 % 4 = 2
```

As I understand it, the *modulo* operator returns the remainder of a division. So 2 divided by (-4) gives (-0.5). How does Python3 calculate the remainder of that as 2?

I know it's stupid but what's the reasoning behind that result?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly, if $a$ is an integer and $b>0$ is a positive integers then you can find an integer $m$ and an integer $r \in \{0,\ldots,b-1\}$ such that
$$
a = mb + r.
$$
We say that $m$ is the *quotient* and $r$ is the *remainder*. For example, if $a=2$ and $b=4$ then $m=0$ and $r=2$.

When $b$ is allowed to be negative, the exact meaning is language-specific. You can work out the case of python by trying a few examples.